# How to correct sign bitcoin cash inputs with libbitcoin?

Tags: c++, bitcoin

I try to use libbitcoin for create bitcoin CASH transaction
I used this example - https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin/wiki/Building-Transactions with my BITCOIN prv/pub/inputs/outputs/etc It's work correctly.
For bitcoin CASH i use my prv/pub/inputs/outputs/etc and set sighash_algorithm "all | 0x40". As described in bitcoin cash manuals, we need use SIGHASH_FORKID = 0x40(bit 6 set) to sign transaction.
"Electron cash" also use this sighash_algorithm. I look on differents with https://github.com/Electron-Cash/Electron-Cash/blob/master/lib/transaction.py https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/blob/master/electrum/transaction.py and see it

electron cash:

def nHashType(cls):
'''Hash type in hex.'''
return 0x01 | (cls.SIGHASH_FORKID + (cls.FORKID << 8))

electron cash:

def serialize_preimage(self, i):
nVersion = int_to_hex(self.version, 4)
nHashType = int_to_hex(**self.nHashType()**, 4)

electrum-btc:

def serialize_preimage(self, i):
nVersion = int_to_hex(self.version, 4)
nHashType = int_to_hex(**1**, 4)

.....
so,if use sighash_algorithm "0x01" with bitcoin CASH transaction, i got answer from electrum node:

```
the transaction was rejected by network rules.\n\n16: mandatory-script-verify-flag-failed (Signature must use SIGHASH_FORKID)
```

OK,after this answer i use 0x40 | 0x01 and got this answer

```
the transaction was rejected by network rules.\n\n16: mandatory-script-verify-flag-failed (Signature must be zero for failed CHECK(MULTI)SIG operation)
```

I make similar rawtx in electron cash.My rawtx and rawtx from electron cash are different. electron cash rawtx - correct.

How to correct sign bitcoin CASH inputs with libbitcoin?
sry for my english, but i hope you understand this